# C# transparent forms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

How can I build transparent form look like windows vista weather gadget? Is there any example for this?

This is basically what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use WPF. Winforms are not suitable for creating transparent forms.